# How to show the po_number in sales order grid and My order Table at frontend - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, payment, order-grid

How the show **po_number** from sales_order_payment_table to **Sales order grid** in admin html and **My order tabel** at frontend after customer login.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

observe the event on **Sales order grid** and create a check of customer login if customer in login then load the collection and show the required info form collection

further more can take a look here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001897/magento-2-how-to-customise-admin-sales-order-grid-collection

Comment: Thanks For your answer ! I hadd shown in the sales order Grid now i want to show in the Frontend @asad Ullah